# Show that $\lambda(M_\varepsilon) <\infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, where $ f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}1_{[-n^2,n^2]}(x)$

Tags: measure-theory

I am self-studying measure theory and am stuck on a problem:

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}1_{[-n^2,n^2]}(x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

For every $\varepsilon \geq 0$, define the set
$$M_\varepsilon = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \; : \: f(x)>\varepsilon\}.$$

Show that $\lambda(M_\varepsilon) <\infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

---

I would think that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the interval $[-n^2,n^2]$ would eventually contain this $x$, and then the sum $f(x)$ would be greater than an $\varepsilon \leq 0$. But clearly the answer can't be all of the real line, because the Lebesgue measure of the real line is not finite.
This makes me think that maybe I am not understanding the problem correctly.

I have no ideas on how to proceed, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall Chebyshev's Inequality:

$$\lambda\bigg(\{x \ |\  f(x) > \epsilon\}\bigg) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_{|f(x)| > \epsilon} f(x) 
 \ dx$$
So that we have,
$$\lambda(M_{\epsilon}) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) = \frac{2}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^4} = \frac{2}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty $$

Where the interchanging of the integral and sum is justified by the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

first, if we integrated the function then its value finitely exist and f is a measurable function so the set {x:f(x)>£) is a measurable set therefore if we integrated the function over that set it also finitely exist. if the measure of the set is infinite then the integration must be infinite. but the integration finitely exist by monotone convergence theorem of integration.